# wix uninstall - how to force admin privileges

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, admin

Wix installation - my install asks the user for admin privileges and I'd like the **uninstall** to do the same. How can I do that?
I think that the related code in my wxs file, that asks for admin in install  is somewhere here :

```
  <MsiPackage SourceFile="../RAInstallerMsi.msi">
    <vi:ExtendedInstallSize InstallDirProperty='INSTALLFOLDER'  />
    <MsiProperty Name='INSTALLFOLDER' Value='[INSTALLDIR]'/>
  </MsiPackage>
```

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Adding the attribute ForcePerMachine="yes" to the MsiPackage should solve your issue.